# Vuetify - Изменение цвета хедера при скролле

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify

Я делаю сайт на vue+vuetify, и мне необходимо сделать чтобы при скролле страницы хедер менял свой цвет. Как я это могу сделать? Для хедера я использую элемент `v-app-bar`. Как мне обратится к элементу и изменить цвет?

Код

```
  <v-app-bar
      app
      class="header"
      color="dark"
      dark
      style="background-color:#fff0"
  >
<!-- some code... -->
</v-app-bar>
```

Comment: Вы пробовали повесить слушателя на скролл и меня цвет когда это событие срабатывает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте директиву `v-scroll`, чтобы отследить скролл элемента:

```
<v-container style="height: 800px;" v-scroll:#scrollarea="onScroll">
```

Атрибут `color` для компонента `v-app-bar` сделайте динамическим:

```
<v-app-bar app flat :color="color">
```

При скролле - меняйте цвет на желаемый, используя [метод](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods) (можете [вычисляемое свойство](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed))

```
methods: {
    onScroll(e) {
      this.scrollTop = e.target.scrollTop;
      this.color = (e.target.scrollTop > 100) ? 'green darken-1' : '';
    },
  },
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#apps",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      color: '',
      scrollTop: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onScroll(e) {
      this.scrollTop = e.target.scrollTop;
      this.color = (e.target.scrollTop > 40) ? 'green darken-1' : '';
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<html style="overflow-y: auto;">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="apps">
  <v-app flat>
    <v-app-bar app flat :color="color">
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-toolbar-title>Logo   / scrollTop {{ scrollTop }}px </v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-main>
      <v-sheet id="scrollarea" style="overflow-y:auto" max-height="130">
        <v-container style="height: 800px;" v-scroll:#scrollarea="onScroll">
        </v-container>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А обязательно надо делать 2 скролла на странице? Мне так не надо...

Comment: @MrLivixx, я использовал такую структуру страницы, чтобы показать как изменить цвет хеадера, если вы о скролле, который добавляется стилями `Vuetify` к `<html>` - вот здесь (https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1197) можно подробнее почитать об этом. Тем не менее изменил пример. Спасибо за внимание)